# Install spring based application on Tomcat

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, tomcat, spring-security

I've installed application on ROOT and on admin context. Both application was created on Spring Framework 3.1.2 and Maven struct. When I try run application I get error:

```
Aug 7, 2012 5:20:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet  threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment
    (...)
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Aug 7, 2012 5:21:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:529)
    (...)
```

I have spring-web in my classpath. My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.sitemesh.config.ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error/404.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/error/500.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

In your application context (or through annotations) you do not have a bean defined with the name springSecurityFilterChain.

Comment: I've never hear about defined springSecurityFilterChain in bean. Can you show me how can I do this?

Comment: You are going to have read up on Spring. Spring bean's are like step one of learning Spring. Any online tutorial will discuss them.

Comment: Of course. But springSecurityFilterChain is default bean from Spring context, so I shouldn't define him. I suppose the real problem is with org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment, but I cannot find information about it.

Comment: It is not defined in the web.xml file, it would be defined in your servlet context or root context file.

Comment: Ok I do it. I have now only error with StandardServletEnvironment.